# unresolved includes inside <stdio.h> in netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans, include, cygwin, netbeans-8

I recently installed netbeans in my windows 10 and it seems to work fine
but I am getting this error

Library File C:\cygwin64\usr\include\stdio.h but there is an unresolved #include "../tlsoffsets64.h" in included C:\cygwin64\usr\include\cygwin\config.h

There is a yellow bulb symbol on side of `#include<stdio.h>` which on hovering shows the error.

[image]

Now when I ctrl+Alt+Click on the error it takes me to config.h file and shows the error as below

[image]

I dont know how to solve it nor I can find any solution anywhere.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Copy&paste the exact error message as text. Do you get the error from the compiler/linker when you try to build your program? In this case also show the command that prints the error message. Or is it only an error message in the IDE that does not affect building the program?

Comment: the include are protect from `#if defined (_COMPILING_NEWLIB) || defined (__INSIDE_CYGWIN__)` . I assume you are not building neither of them, so it is a false positive

Comment: @Bodo I have edited my question. I hope it is clear now?